# Detect old firefox versions

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, browser

Is there anyway to detect old browsers in HTML like the code I use for IE e.g :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

I want to show a warning message as some of my web features are not supported for them.Is it better to use a JavaScript to detect this instead ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's better to use JavaScript and do feature detection instead of browser detection.

Comment: As a side remark, it may not be necessary to track this down... most FF users are quite up-to-date with their version...

Comment: Hi Bartdude, it is as I had several complains about this, so I have to show a message to all of them

Answer (score 1):

I finally used the code found at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#92310

by using PHP

Answer (score 1):

**Feature detection. Not browser detection.**

If you want to warn them about missing web features, why not use feature detection for those specific features, rather than browser version detection?

This has two major advantages:

Firstly, for your code, it has the advantage of making it clear what you're actually doing, and why you're doing it. This will make your code easier to work with in the future.

Secondly, this will allow you to reliably pick up **all** browsers that don't have the feature(s) you need, which means that if someone visits your site using (for example) and old mobile phone browser that's never been updated, you'll still be able to pick it up and show the correct message, even though you never thought to test for that specific browser.

You didn't tell use which specific features your site needs, so I can't give you details of how to detect it, but you may find the [Modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/) useful; it does feature detection for a wide range of modern browser features.

You may also have the option to add a 'polyfill' to your site to add support for the missing feature to old browsers. Modernizr is good for helping with this, and they also have [a big list of polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) you might like to try.